# How to exclude a word while using re.sub in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a fair amount of possessives and I am trying to clean them accordingly.

I want to exclude a word or two while removing them. Here is my not working example so far:

```
import re
re.sub(r"(s')", '', "united states' and washingtons' and civilians' and qur'an")
```

In the above case, I would like 'states' to not get sliced off. Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative look behind, `'(?<!something)'`  to tell regex to only slice the words that doesn't have `'state'` right behind the `"s'"`:

```
import re
print(re.sub(r"(?<! state)s'", '', "united states' and washingtons' and civilians' and qur'an"))
```

Output:

```
united states' and washington and civilian and qur'an
```

---

Comment: Thank you so much, I was playing with the look up like this, but I failed to specify it like this: `<!state)s`. Thanks !

Comment: `"(?<!state)s'"` will not match `s'` in `estates'`

Comment: Not finding `estates'` is fine, but how would you then handle it?

Comment: @JohnStud Fixed it with a whitespace :)